# SQL Query to retrieve data while excluding a set of rows

Tags: sql

I have basically four tables (SQL Server):

```
Objects:
id
ObjectName

Components
id
ComponentName

ObjectsDetails:
ObjectID
ComponentID

ExclusionTable
id
ComponentID
```

Basically, these tables describe Objects and what Objects are made of (what components)

For example, Object "A" may be made out of component "A" and component "B".

In this case, the tables would be populated this way:

Objects:
id   ObjectName
1      A

Components:
id   ComponentName
1      A
2      B

ObjectDetails:
ObjectID  ComponentID
   1          1
   1          2

Now, "ExclusionTable" may have a list of components that are to be excluded from a search (therefore, excluding entire objects if the object is made out of at least one of those components).

For example, I would like to ask:

"Give me all the Objects that are not made out of components A and B".

Therefore, my question is:

Is there a way to write a query for that ? No views, no stored procedures please.. my SQL engine does not support that.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ObjectName FROM Objects INNER JOIN ObjectsDetails ON Objects.id =    
ObjectDetails.ObjectID WHERE ObjectsDetails.ComponentID NOT IN (1,2)
```

in case ExclusionTable tells us that Components A and B needs to be excluded.

Of course, that doesn't work...

I tried a few variations using WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ExclusionTable) but I am not proficient enough in SQL to understand how to get it to work using one query only (if it is even possible).

Thanks!

Comment: You state you want to exclude components, but your exclusion table has ObjectId, not ComponentId... is this a typo, or intentional?

Comment: Hi, 

It's a typo; I'm very sorry for that. As you said, it should be ComponentID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if you need to get all objects not made from A or B, you need to get all objects EXCEPT those made from A or B.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, ObjectName 
FROM Objects 
WHERE Id NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT ObjectDetails.ObjectID 
FROM ObjectDetails
INNER JOIN Components ON ObjectDetails.ComponentID = Components.Id
WHERE Components.ComponentName = 'A' OR Components.ComponentName = 'B'
)
```

Would that be what you're looking for?

EDIT: Of course, you can omit the join if you already have the component ids - then just put those in the where clause to filter them out.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid doing queries with `[not] in (select ...)`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ObjectName 
FROM Objects 
INNER JOIN ObjectsDetails ON Objects.id = ObjectDetails.ObjectID 
LEFT JOIN ExclusionTable on ExclusionTable.ComponentId = ObjectsDetails.ComponentID
where ExclusionTable.ComponentId is null;
```

This will retrieve only rows for which the ComponentID is not in ExclusionTable.

Update:

```
SELECT ObjectName 
FROM Objects
INNER JOIN ObjectsDetails ON Objects.id = ObjectDetails.ObjectID 
LEFT JOIN ExclusionTable on ExclusionTable.ComponentId = ObjectsDetails.ComponentID
group by ObjectName 
having count(distinct ObjectsDetails.ComponentID) = sum(case when ExclusionTable.id is null then 1 else 0 end)
```

New approach, I think the only other way I could do it is basically to compare the number of components per object with the number of components in the object not included on the list. When these number are equal, no component is on the excluded list and we can show the object.

I'm sorry I can't make a test right now, please use `EXPLAIN select ...` to compare the queries, if they work.

Comment: Quite true, this is a much better solution from a performance perspective.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately, the query returns all the objects. I have a test database that contains 4 objects: A, B, C and D. Similarly, there are 4 components: CA, CB, CC, CD. 

Object A is made of CA,CB, object B is made out of CA,CD, object C is made out of CC,CD and object D is made out of CB, CD. 

The exclusion table contains components CA and CC. Therefore, the query should only return object D since it is made of neither CA or CC while the other ones are made of at least one object included in the exclusion table. However, the query returns all objects. Thanks again!

Comment: I am still interested to find a solution that is performance friendly. Therefore, I've done some testing and your query, at least logically, seems correct. For example, if I change the WHERE clause to read "WHERE ExclusionTable.ComponentID IS NOT NULL" then all the objects, except D are displayed (the expected behavior). However, if I leave it as is, all objects are displayed. I even tried to insert a NULL in the ExclusionTable but that didn't help either. Any ideas why it doesn't work ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

select id, objectname 
from Objects
left outer join 
( select objectid from ObjectsDetails od inner join Exclusiontable  et
on od.ComponentID= et.ComponentID) excludedid
on Objects.ID = excludedid.ObjectID and excludedid.ObjectID is null

Comment: Unfortunately, this query returns all the objects.